# Custom MkPointAnnotation not loading correctly after reading via NSCoding

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having the darndest time with this.  I have a MKMapView in which I add an annotation to it when the user performs a long-press and this works.  The user can click the annotation and a nice callout appears.  However, if I stored the annotations and load them back in using the NSCoding protocol they appear in the correct coordinates although they are un-clickable.

Encoding of the Annotation class:

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {

    [encoder encodeInteger:_type forKey:kType];
    [encoder encodeObject:_note forKey:kNote];

    NSMutableArray* coord = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [coord addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.coordinate.latitude]];
    [coord addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.coordinate.longitude]];

    [encoder encodeObject:coord forKey:kCoordinate];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {

    NSString* note = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kNote];
    NSInteger type = [decoder decodeIntegerForKey:kType];
    NSMutableArray* coord = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kCoordinate];

    double lat = [(NSString *)[coord objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
    double lon = [(NSString *)[coord objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coords = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){ lat, lon };
    return [self initWithAttrs:coords note:note type:type];
}
```

Loading the data and storing in an NSMutableArray

```
- (void) saveData {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"appData"];

    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.annotations toFile:filePath];
}

- (void) loadData {
    // look for saved data.
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"appData"];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSArray *savedData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
        self.annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:savedData];
    }
}
```

And now for what works and what doesn't.  I'm stumped!
Okay, this works.  A pin is dropped, the user can click on the pin all day and the callout appears

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        return;

    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.mapView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate =
        [self.mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];

    Annotation* a = [[Annotation alloc]init];
    a.coordinate = touchMapCoordinate;
    a.title = @"test2";
    [self.annotations addObject:a];

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:a];
    [self saveData];
}
```

And this doesn't work.  It should effectively be doing exactly the same thing as during the long press.  Someone please enlighten me (I realize there's also a 'addAnnotations' method).

```
- (void)mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView fullyRendered:(BOOL)fullyRendered
{
    for(Annotation* anno in self.annotations){
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:anno];
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, for the annotations loaded in during startup "didSelectAnnotationView" is never called when selecting them.  Once I place markers after the app starts up it's called as one would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a fair amount of time debugging this I found the answer and I'm about to kill something. Opps, that's probably not allowed on here is it?

In any case, if an annotation doesn't have the title set the callout won't display.  It's the simple things....